# Kicker on high card

Tags: texas-hold-em

I want to know who wins the game with the following cards

Player A : 3 4 
Player B : 5 6

On the Table : A K Q J 2 (No flush)

So Does Player B wins because his 5th card is higher? Or is it a split pot?

Answer (score 1):

Player B wins since his hand (A K Q J 6) is higher in rank than the hand of player A (A K Q J 4).

Poker hands always consist of five cards.

Answer (score 0):

TmKVU got it.

While each player has 7 cards to use, it's the best **5** card hand that wins.

PlayerB's pot.  All of it.